# How to get the id of a single topic in Bbpress

Tags: wordpress

I was trying to display a single topic from a page via shortcode of bbpress.

I referred to this list btw: https://codex.bbpress.org/features/shortcodes/

so using that codex I came to this:

[bbp-single-topic id=11132016]

This one doesnt work.

I look at the list but there is no id there.

[image]

[image]

[image]

How do I diplay then a single topic on specific page usign shortcodes?

Can't see any id here.

Answer (score 0):

On the admin side, when you open the topic for editing, you will see the ID in the URL address bar.